# TypeError: Cannot perform 'get' on a proxy that has been revoked, redux-toolkit and nextJS

Tags: redux, react-redux, next.js, redux-thunk, redux-toolkit

I'm get the error in tittle when a action is dispatched to redux in a next application and i can't find the solution: the first action is correctly dispatched but others raises the error: **TypeError: Cannot perform 'get' on a proxy that has been revoked**, redux-toolkit and nextJS, you can see the project in the follow link : https://github.com/cpereiramt/BACKBONE-TEST

Below I share the mainly snippets of code and the configuration in general :

configuring store:

```
import {
  configureStore,
  EnhancedStore,
  getDefaultMiddleware
} from "@reduxjs/toolkit"
import { MakeStore } from "next-redux-wrapper"
import { Env } from "../constants"
import { rootReducer, RootState } from "./reducers"
import { createWrapper } from 'next-redux-wrapper';

/**
 * @see https://redux-toolkit.js.org/usage/usage-with-typescript#correct-typings-for-the-dispatch-type
 */
const middlewares = [...getDefaultMiddleware<RootState>()]

const store = configureStore({
  reducer: rootReducer,
  middleware: middlewares,
  devTools: Env.NODE_ENV === "development",
})

const makeStore: MakeStore = (_?: RootState): EnhancedStore => store
export  const wrapper = createWrapper(makeStore);
```

combineReducers

```
import { combineReducers } from "redux"
import { contactReducer } from "./contact"

/**
 * Combine reducers
 * @see https://redux-toolkit.js.org/usage/usage-with-typescript
 */
export const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  contacts: contactReducer,
})

export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof rootReducer>
```

actions

```
import { createAsyncThunk } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { Contact } from "../../model";
import { FeatureKey } from "../featureKey";

/**
 * Fetch all contact action
 */
export const fetchAllContactsAction = createAsyncThunk(
  `${FeatureKey.CONTACT}/fetchAll`,
  async (arg: { offset: number; limit: number }) => {
    const { offset, limit } = arg
    const url = `/api/contact?offset=${offset}&limit=${limit}`
    const result: Contact[] = await fetch(url, {
      method: "get",
    }).then((response: Response) => response.json())
    return { contacts: result }
  }
)

/**
 * Fetch contact action
 */
export const fetchContactAction = createAsyncThunk(
  `${FeatureKey.CONTACT}/fetch`,
  async (arg: { id: number }) => {

    const url = `/api/contact/${arg}`
    const result: Contact = await fetch(url, {
      method: "get",
    }).then((response: Response) => response.json())
    return { contacts: result }
  }
)

/**
 * Add contact action
 */
export const addContactAction = createAsyncThunk(
  `${FeatureKey.CONTACT}/add`,
  async (arg: { contact: Contact }) => {
       const url = `/api/contact`
    const result: Contact = await fetch(url, {
      method: "post",
      headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
      body: JSON.stringify(arg),
    }).then((response: Response) => response.json())
    return { contacts: result }
  }
)

/**
 * Edit contact action
 */
export const editContactAction = createAsyncThunk(
  `${FeatureKey.CONTACT}/edit`,
   (arg: { contact: Contact }) => {
    const { contact } = arg
    const url = `/api/contact/${arg.id}`
    const result: Contact =  fetch(url, {
      method: "put",
      headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
      body: JSON.stringify(contact),
    }).then((response: Response) => response.json())
    return { contacts: result }
  }
)

/**
 * Delete contact action
 */
export const deleteContactAction = createAsyncThunk(
  `${FeatureKey.CONTACT}/delete`,
  async (arg: { id: number }) => {
    const url = `/api/contact/${arg}`
    await fetch(url, {
      method: "delete",
    })
  }
)
```

reducers

```
import { ActionReducerMapBuilder, createReducer } from "@reduxjs/toolkit"
import {
  addContactAction,
  deleteContactAction,
  editContactAction,
  fetchAllContactsAction,
  fetchContactAction
} from "./action"
import { adapter, ContactState, initialState } from "./state"

/**
 * CONTACT reducer
 */
export const contactReducer = createReducer(
  initialState,
  (builder: ActionReducerMapBuilder<ContactState>) =>
    builder
      .addCase(fetchAllContactsAction.pending, (state) => {
        return { ...state, isFetching: true }
      })
      .addCase(fetchAllContactsAction.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
        const { contacts } = action.payload
        return adapter.setAll({ ...state, isFetching: false }, contacts)
      })
      .addCase(fetchAllContactsAction.rejected, (state) => {
        return { ...state, isFetching: false }
      })
      //-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      .addCase(fetchContactAction.pending, (state, action) => {
        const { id } = action.meta.arg
        return { ...state, isFetching: true, selectedId: id }
      })
      .addCase(fetchContactAction.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
        const { contacts } = action.payload
        return adapter.upsertOne({ ...state, isFetching: false }, contacts)
      })
      .addCase(fetchContactAction.rejected, (state) => {
        return { ...state, isFetching: false }
      })
      //-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      .addCase(addContactAction.pending, (state, action) => {
        const { contact } = action.meta.arg
        return { ...state, isFetching: true, selectedId: contact?.id }
      })
      .addCase(addContactAction.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
        const { contacts } = action.payload
        return adapter.addOne({ ...state, isFetching: false }, contacts)
      })
      .addCase(addContactAction.rejected, (state) => {
        return { ...state, isFetching: false }
      })
      //-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      .addCase(editContactAction.pending, (state, action) => {
        const { contact } = action.meta.arg
        return { ...state, isFetching: true, selectedId: contact?.id }
      })
      .addCase(editContactAction.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
        const { contacts } = action.payload
        return adapter.updateOne(
          { ...state, isFetching: false },
          {
            id: contacts.id,
            changes: contacts,
          }
        )
      })
      .addCase(editContactAction.rejected, (state) => {
        return { ...state, isFetching: false }
      })
      //-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      .addCase(deleteContactAction.pending, (state, action) => {
        const { id } = action.meta.arg
        return { ...state, isFetching: true, selectedId: id }
      })
      .addCase(deleteContactAction.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
        const { id } = action.meta.arg
        return adapter.removeOne({ ...state, isFetching: false }, id)
      })
      .addCase(deleteContactAction.rejected, (state) => {
        return { ...state, isFetching: false }
      })
)
```

selectors

```
import { createSelector } from "@reduxjs/toolkit"
import { RootState } from "../reducers"
import { adapter, ContactState } from "./state"

const { selectAll, selectEntities } = adapter.getSelectors()

const featureStateSelector = (state: RootState) => state.contacts

const entitiesSelector = createSelector(featureStateSelector, selectEntities)

/**
 * isFetching selector
 */
export const isFetchingSelector = createSelector(
  featureStateSelector,
  (state: ContactState) => state?.isFetching
)

/**
 * selectedId selector
 */
export const selectedIdSelector = createSelector(
  featureStateSelector,
  (state: ContactState) => state?.selectedId
)

/**
 * all contact selector
 */
export const allContactSelector = createSelector(featureStateSelector, selectAll)

/**
 * contact selector
 */
export const contactSelector = createSelector(
  entitiesSelector,
  selectedIdSelector,
  (entities, id) => (id ? entities[id] || null : null)
)
```

states

```
import { createEntityAdapter, EntityState } from "@reduxjs/toolkit"
import { Contact } from "../../model"

export interface ContactState extends EntityState<Contact> {
  isFetching: boolean
  selectedId: number | null
}

export const adapter = createEntityAdapter<Contact>({
  selectId: (contacts: Contact) => contacts.id,
})

export const initialState: ContactState = adapter.getInitialState({
  isFetching: false,
  selectedId: null,
})
```

And the _app file

```
import CssBaseline from "@material-ui/core/CssBaseline";
import { ThemeProvider } from "@material-ui/styles";
import { NextPageContext } from 'next';
import App from "next/app";
import React from "react";
import { MuiTheme } from "../components/MuiTheme";
import { Store } from '../redux/store';
import { wrapper } from "../store/configureStore";
import "../styles/main.css";

interface AppContext extends NextPageContext {
  store: Store;
}

class MyApp extends App<AppContext> {
  componentDidMount() {
    // Remove the server-side injected CSS.
    const jssStyles = document.querySelector("#jss-server-side")
    jssStyles?.parentNode?.removeChild(jssStyles)
  }

  render() {
    const {  Component, ...props } = this.props;

    return (

        <ThemeProvider theme={MuiTheme}>
          {/* CssBaseline kickstart an elegant, consistent, and simple baseline to build upon. */}
          <CssBaseline />
          <Component {...props} />
        </ThemeProvider>

    )
  }
}

export default wrapper.withRedux(MyApp);
```

And in index file the action fetchAllContacts() work without problems.

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import ContactTable from "../components/Table/";
import { useContact } from "../hooks";
import { Contact } from '../model/Contact';
import appStyles from "./indexStyles";
type Props = {}

function Index(props: Props) {
  const { fetchAllContacts } = useContact();
  const [contacts, setContacts] = React.useState<Contact[]>([])


    useEffect(() => {
      const results = fetchAllContacts();
      results.then(data => console.log(data));
      results.then(data => setContacts(data.contacts));

  }, [])
  const classes = appStyles(props)
   return (

     <div className={classes.indexBackground}>
       <div className={classes.indexTabletDiv}>
         <ContactTable contacts={contacts}  />
         </div>
    </div>
  );

}



export default Index
```

But when I try to use the action addContact() in another component the error is raised

page add

```
import { Button, createStyles, InputLabel, makeStyles, TextField, Theme } from "@material-ui/core";
import router from "next/router";
import React from "react";
import { useContact } from "../../hooks";

const useStyles = makeStyles((_: Theme) =>
  createStyles({
    root: {},
  })
)

type Props = { }
const AddContact = (props: Props) => {
    const { addContact } = useContact();
  const newContact = {
    id:'455666gghghttttytyty',
    firstName: 'clayton',
    lastName: 'pereira',
    email: 'cpereiramt@gmail.com',
    phone: '5565992188269',
  }
  const handleCreateContact =   () => {
    addContact(newContact);

  }
  const { } = props

  return (

    <div style={{margin: '10px', display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'space-between', wrap: 'wrap', flexDirection:'column'}}>

        <>
          <InputLabel>Name </InputLabel><TextField   />
          <InputLabel>Last Name </InputLabel><TextField   />
          <InputLabel>Email </InputLabel><TextField   />
          <div>
          <Button variant="outlined" color="primary" onClick={() => handleCreateContact(newContact)} >
            Create Contact</Button>
           <Button variant="outlined" color="primary" onClick={() => router.push('/')} >
          Back</Button>
          </div>
        </>
</div>
    )


}

export default AddContact;
```

Answer (score 1):

I *think* I see the issue.

First, the actual error message is Immer telling you that something is trying to modify the `Proxy`-wrapped `state` in a reducer, but long after the reducer has actually finished running.  Normally that's impossible, because reducers are synchronous.  So, there has to be some kind of async behavior going on.

The case reducers themselves seem basically okay, and mostly look like this:

```js
      .addCase(fetchAllContactsAction.pending, (state) => {
        return { ...state, isFetching: true }
      })
```

I'll point out that Immer lets you write `state.isFetching = true` instead, so you *don't* have to do object spreads :)  But this code should run fine, and it's synchronous.  So, what's the problem?

You didn't actually describe *which* actions are causing errors, so I'm having to guess.  But, I *think* it's in one of the async thunks, and specifically, here:

```
export const editContactAction = createAsyncThunk(
  `${FeatureKey.CONTACT}/edit`,
   (arg: { contact: Contact }) => {
    const { contact } = arg
    const url = `/api/contact/${arg.id}`

    // PROBLEM 1
    const result: Contact =  fetch(url, {
      method: "put",
      headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
      body: JSON.stringify(contact),
    }).then((response: Response) => response.json())

    // PROBLEM 2
    return { contacts: result }
  }
```

Notice the line `const result: Contact =  fetch()`.  This doesn't have any `await` in there  So, this is going to end up returning a `Promise` and saving it as `result`, and then that `Promise` ends up being returned as the `contacts` field.

I *think* that the object with the promise is being put into Redux state, wrapped by an Immer proxy, and then modified sometime *later*, and that's what's causing the error.  But I'm not 100% sure because I don't know which actions are actually involved.

Comment: First thanks for you support,
In this case bot editContactAction() and addContactAction() is given the same error to me and unfortunately put await in action fetch don't solve this exception

Comment: Hmm. The other potential issue is that your payload creation function _should_ be returning a promise itself, and it looks like you're returning a plain JS object.  You either need to mark the callback function as `async`, or explicitly return a `Promise` that will resolve with the result value.